# Desktop slack app showing employee ID instead of employee name

Tags: slack

Recently, I have joined in a new company & workspace and desktop slack app is showing the employee IDs instead of their employee names. Its showing ID for all the users instead of names.

Is there any setting or configuration which might be causing this ?

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: I have tried restarting slack and rebooted system with no luck

Comment: Can you please check `Display Name` in the profile section?

Comment: Display name seems to be employee name

Comment: Can you please attach the snap? It could help to troubleshoot quite faster. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @HenonoaH, after setting "preferences > messages & media > Names" to "just display names" instead of "Full & display names" this seems to be resolved